# pathForResorce doesn't work with NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a jpg picture in my "Other Sources" folder, on xcode. Nice. But I'm trying to add this image to my NSMutableArray.

```
[self.gallery addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"001" ofType:@"jpg"]];

NSLog(@"%i", [self.gallery count]);
```

When I counts it, it returns 0.

What's happening?

Comment: have you initialized your 'gallery' array anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, thats was the problem. But now, looks like my app arent finding the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either `self.gallery` is nil or there is no image `001.jpg` in your bundle

Comment: Oh, i found the problem. I wasnt initializing the array. But now, my picture dont show where suppost to. And its on Other Sources folder. [self.gallery addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"001" ofType:@"jpg"]];

Comment: Being in "Other Sources" isn't enough -- you have to add your jpg to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase of your application.

Comment: Best way to check this is to do a right click on the header in "Groups % Files" and select "Target Membership". Make sure there is a checkmark in front of your image files.